# change date without access to OS

Tags: php, .htaccess, date, time, timezone

Our server administrators are unavailable for a long time and server time is wrong. It should be changed to +3min. How can i change this via php or htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use PHP's exec (http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) command to run terminal commands.

Not all servers enable exec for security reasons, so you will need to check first.